# Can data be changed without changing it's hash?

Tags: hash, blockchain

The goal is to prove that some piece of data existed at the specific moment of time.

I assume I can achieve this by storing data hash in ethereum blockchain and the data itself somewhere else, where storage is cheap.

Let's say it's an article we are talking about. It has mostly text and few high-res images. So, it's size is relatively big. I want to generate hash to identify this article and store it in ethereum blockchain. If one needs proof that this article existed at some point of time, he can use the same protocol to generate hash from the article stored in whatever database/datastorage and compare it with the hash stored in blockchain.
Hopefully i'm using "hash" word correctly here.

1. Will this work?
2. Is there way to change the data without changing it's hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to establish '*proof of authenticity*' using hashes.
That has been done by many products in the market and yes, its a viable strategy when the data is large and thereby not susceptible to rainbow table attacks.

What you need to ensure is that you use '*one-way hashing*' and an algorithm which offers '*strong collision resistance*' and you will be fine.
By doing this, it is nearly impossible to have two data streams with the same hash.

Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function and http://crppit.epfl.ch/documentation/Hash_Function/WiKi/Hash_collision.htm for more info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: could you post links to some of those products that are using it?

Comment: There's Chainpoint, OpenTimestamps, Stampery, Blocknotary, Eternity Wall, Verisart, Blocksign, etc..
All of these work on the same principle of immutability of blockchain, but offer different flavors of stamping a record.